# Android Studio : how to add 'App quality insight' window to see Crashlytics data in Android Studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

It is mentioned here:
https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/06/new-product-updates-to-firebase-crashlytics

that I can see my Crashlytics crashes directly in Android Studio thanks to the  'App quality insight' window.

As explained in the previous link, I logged in my Android Studio with my Google developer account.

But I don't see how to add the 'App quality insight' window.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available in Electic Eel Release of Android Studio.

> Get access to this feature in the latest Canary version of Android Studio - Electric Eel | 2022.1.1.

Link to official docs: [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=android&authuser=0#next-steps)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had the last version as no updates are available via 'check for updates' in my Android Studio. I will wait to have the update in Android Studio as I don't like to install dev or canary versions.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, firebase plugin was disabled, and I didn't see App Quality Insight window.
After enabling firebase plugins and restarting of Android studio,  App Quality Insight window appears.

File->Settings->Plugins

[image]

Comment: Also you need to be logged in with your developer account

Comment: similar case to me, enabling `Firebase Services` now able to show the `App Quality Insight` as Tool Window

Answer (score 3):

You have to sign in with the same account you use on firebase. Click on avatar at the top right corner in android studio and log in.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have logged in to Android Studio using the same account as your Firebase account.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to Ali Rezaiyan's answer

[image]