# Android Studio App Quality Insights problem

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics

I've updated my Android Studio to the latest version ElectricEel. Everything is working fine, except the App Quality Insights feature(I've updated the Studio because of this :) )

First, my Firebase plugins were disabled and the App Quality Insights window was not available at all. I've fixed this issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74315737/2659925).

Now I have the ability to launch the feature. But when the window is loaded I'm getting an error:

```
400 Bad Request { "error" : "invalid_grant", "error_description" : "Bad Request" }
```

I've checked the Firebase plugins and signed in to Android Studio. Restarted and Invalidated. Nothing helped.

NOTE: My colleagues on the same project don't have this issue.

Any hints about this?

Comment: You can report this to IntelliJ team they will guide on that. I think there is icon in bottom right corner of Android Studio. Or It could be bug in new version of Android Studio. I also noticed that new patch available for Electric ell that could fix your issue. 

Try Invalidate cache and check all boxes and restart.

Comment: Can you able to login to firebase using browser? This error looks like api server error.

Comment: @ArpitPatel Yes, I can login

Answer (score 4):

The fix was in three steps:

1. Sign out from your account in Android Studio;
2. Restart the Android Studio;
3. Sign in again.

Everything should work. Also, if after sign in, you are not seeing your Google account image in the top right corner, u maybe need to re-login again.

Thanks [ArpitPatel] for a hint.

Comment: Thank you! After re-login the avatar appeared, everything worked. It looks like Android Studio needed some additional permissions that are requested at login.

Comment: I am not able to signout can you please tell me the manual way to remove my account

Comment: @SayokMajumder check the upper right corner for the avatar icon and click on it. You should be able to sign out

Comment: No its not showing logout option is there any folder which can be deleted

Comment: I guess u can reinstall the Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac Os you can run from your Terminal:

`defaults delete com.google.gct`

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/300128115